# Easiest way to migrate Word 2003 custom macro toolbars into Word 2007?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I have a series of macros and toolbars that I developed for Word 2003.  Now that my office is upgrading to Word 2007, I need to migrate them.  The macros themselves migrate with zero effort, but the toolbars are a different issue.  A random subset of the toolbars show up in the "Add-Ins" ribbon tab, but I haven't found a way to control which ones.

Something that may be a complication is that I deploy the macros by placing a template into a user's Word STARTUP folder (C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP).  While I can add macros from normal.dot into the Quick Access Toolbar, I cannot add macros from this startup template.  I'd like a better, more structured layout anyway.

So, what's the easiest way to replicate my custom macro toolbars in Word 2007?

Answer (score 1):

The macros and toolbars that I developed for Word 2003 are in a number of .dot files. I simply put these .dot files into my Startup folder. I restarted Word'07 an wallah, these Macro toolbars appeared in the Add-Ins ribbon.

Good Luck